# swiper not allowed to registered in appModule in angular 15

Tags: angular, swiper.js, angular15

```
import { NgxUsefulSwiperModule } from 'ngx-useful-swiper';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxUsefulSwiperModule,
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

this problem give me this error:
NgxUsefulSwiperModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002) ngx-useful-swiper.module.d.ts(1, 22): This likely means that the library (ngx-useful-swiper) which declares NgxUsefulSwiperModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy. (alias) class NgxUsefulSwiperModule import NgxUsefulSwiperModule

### how can i use swiper in angular 15 or fix this error? thanks

Comment: The lib is really not magic. You can copy it in your own project https://github.com/JayChase/angular2-useful-swiper/blob/master/projects/ngx-useful-swiper/src/lib/swiper/swiper.component.ts + the style